# Ruby URI module oddness in modular Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, uri

I'm having trouble using the Ruby [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module's `encode_www_form` method in a modular Sinatra app. For some reason, `URI` is interpreted as being the `URI::Parser` subclass, and so the method call understandably fails.

I've reduced this to a minimal test case. The `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'sinatra'
```

And `app.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Frontend < Sinatra::Base
  get '/test/' do
    URI.encode_www_form(:a => 1, :b => 2)
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

If I then run `ruby app.rb` and access `/test/` I get:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `encode_www_form' for #<URI::Parser:0x007fa9221ca868>:
    app.rb:6:in `block in <class:Frontend>'
```

If I convert it to a classic-style Sinatra app, so that `app.rb` is like this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/test/' do
  URI.encode_www_form(:a => 1, :b => 2)
end
```

Then call `ruby app.rb` and access `/test/`, the page shows "a=1&b=2" as desired.

So what's going wrong in the modular format that means something's up with URI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Sinatra::Base` redefines `URI` on line 856 of https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb, which is why your `URI` reference gets evaluated as that value.

If you want to avoid this problem, you can change your reference to `::URI`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Peter! I didn't know about using `::` as a prefix, but I do now. I'm not sure how I should have realised this was the problem - seems strange to me (with a beginner's Ruby knowledge) that `URI` could be changed like this.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that any variable can be redefined in Ruby.  I'd actually forgotten about that notation, but was reminded of it by the line of source code that I found. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As of Sinatra 1.4.4, the URI module is [no longer overwritten](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/775).

Answer (score -2):

I tried to reproduce this in `irb`. This may sound stupid, but `require 'uri'` did the trick there.

Comment: Well, yes, but then you're in an entirely different situation, without inheriting `Sinatra::Base`.

Comment: yea, but it was worth a try :D